# Update cart drawer without reloading the page in shopify

Tags: shopify

I want to update cart drawer when I click on add to cart button currently  got value but only when I reload the page is there any way to refresh value without reloading page. I am using debut theme.

This is my code:

```
<form action="{{ routes.cart_url }}" method="post" novalidate class="cart">

        
        <div  class="cart_popup_wrapper" data-cart-line-items>
          {%- for item in cart.items -%}
            <div  class="cart__row" data-cart-item data-cart-item-key="{{ item.key }}" data-cart-item-url="{{ item.url }}" data-cart-item-title="{{ item.title }}" data-cart-item-index="{{ forloop.index }}" data-cart-item-quantity="{{ item.quantity }}">
              <div  class="cart_popup" data-cart-table-cell>
                <div class="cart__product-information cart_popup_data">
                  <div class="cart_popup_image-wrapper">
                    <img class="cart__image{% if item.image == null %} hide{% endif %}" src="{{ item | img_url: 'x190' }}" alt="{{ item.image.alt | escape }}" data-cart-item-image>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cart_popup_data">
                    <div class="list-view-item__title">
                      <a href="{{ item.url }}" class="cart__product-title" data-cart-item-title>
                        {{ item.product.title }}
                      </a>
                    </div>

                    {%- assign variant_options = 'template ' | split: ' ' -%}
                    {%- if item.product.has_only_default_variant != true -%}
                      {%- assign variant_options = item.options_with_values -%}
                    {%- endif -%}
                    {%- assign property_size = item.properties | size -%}

                    <ul class="product-details{% if item.product.has_only_default_variant and property_size == 0 %} hide{% endif %}" data-cart-item-details aria-label="{{ 'cart.label.product_details' | t }}">
                      {%- for option in variant_options -%}
                        <li class="product-details__item product-details__item--variant-option{% if item.product.has_only_default_variant %} hide{% endif %}" data-cart-item-option>{{ option.name }}: {{ option.value }}</li>
                      {%- endfor -%}
                
                      {%- assign properties = 'template ' | split: ' ' -%}
                      {%- if property_size > 0 -%}
                        {%- assign properties = item.properties -%}
                      {%- endif -%}

                      {%- for p in properties -%}
                        {%- unless p.last == blank -%}
                          <li class="product-details__item product-details__item--property{%if property_size == 0%} hide{% endif %}" data-cart-item-property>
                            <span class="product-details__item-label" data-cart-item-property-name>{{ p.first }}: </span>

                            {%- comment -%}
                              Check if there was an uploaded file associated
                            {%- endcomment -%}
                            <span data-cart-item-property-value>
                              {%- if p.last contains '/uploads/' -%}
                                <a href="{{ p.last }}">{{ p.last | split: '/' | last }}</a>
                              {%- else -%}
                                {{ p.last }}
                              {%- endif -%}
                            </span>
                          </li>
                        {%- endunless -%}
                      {%- endfor -%}
                    </ul>
                    <div  class="cart_popup__price">

                {%- assign hasDiscount = false -%}
                {%- if item.original_price != item.final_price -%}
                  {%- assign hasDiscount = true -%}
                {%- endif -%}

                <div data-cart-item-price>
                  <dl data-cart-item-price-list>
                    {%- comment -%}
                      Markup template for discount item
                    {%- endcomment -%}
                    <div {% unless hasDiscount %}class="hide" {% endunless %}data-cart-item-discounted-price-group>
                      <dt>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t }}</span>
                      </dt>
                      <dd>
                        <s data-cart-item-original-price>{{ item.original_price | money }}</s>
                      </dd>
                      <dt>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.sale_price' | t }}</span>
                      </dt>
                      <dd>
                        <span class="order-discount" data-cart-item-final-price>{{ item.final_price | money }}</span>
                      </dd>
                    </div>

                    {%- comment -%}
                      Markup template for regular price item
                    {%- endcomment -%}
                    <div {% if hasDiscount %}class="hide" {% endif %}data-cart-item-regular-price-group>
                      <dt>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t }}</span>
                      </dt>
                      <dd data-cart-item-regular-price>
                        {{ item.original_price | money }}
                      </dd>
                    </div>

                    {%- comment -%}
                      Markup template for unit price
                    {%- endcomment -%}
                    <div {% unless item.unit_price_measurement %}class="hide" {% endunless %}data-unit-price-group>
                      <dt>
                        <span class="visually-hidden visually-hidden--inline">{{ 'products.product.unit_price_label' | t }}</span>
                      </dt>
                      <dd>
                        <span class="price-unit-price">
                          {%- capture unit_price_separator -%}
                            <span aria-hidden="true">/</span><span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.accessibility.unit_price_separator' | t }}&nbsp;</span>
                          {%- endcapture -%}
                          {%- capture unit_price_base_unit -%}
                            {%- if item.unit_price_measurement.reference_value != 1 -%}
                              {{- item.unit_price_measurement.reference_value -}}
                            {%- endif -%}
                            {{ item.unit_price_measurement.reference_unit }}
                          {%- endcapture -%}

                          <span data-unit-price>{{ item.unit_price | money }}</span>{{- unit_price_separator -}}<span data-unit-price-base-unit>{{- unit_price_base_unit -}}</span>
                        </span>
                      </dd>
                    </div>
                  </dl>
                </div>

                {%- assign itemDiscounts = 'template ' | split: ' ' -%}
                {%- if item.line_level_discount_allocations != blank -%}
                  {%- assign itemDiscounts = item.line_level_discount_allocations -%}
                {%- endif -%}

                <ul class="order-discount order-discount--list order-discount--title order-discount--cart{% if item.line_level_discount_allocations == blank %} hide{% endif %}" aria-label="{{ 'customer.order.discount' | t }}" data-cart-item-discount-list>
                  {%- for discount_allocation in itemDiscounts -%}
                    <li class="order-discount__item" data-cart-item-discount>
                      {% include 'icon-saletag' %}
                      <span data-cart-item-discount-title>
                        {{- discount_allocation.discount_application.title -}}
                      </span> (-<span data-cart-item-discount-amount>{{ discount_allocation.amount | money }}</span>)
                    </li>
                  {%- endfor -%}
                </ul>

                <div class="cart__qty medium-up--hide">
                  <label for="updates_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-label" aria-label="{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}" data-quantity-label-mobile>
                    {{ 'cart.label.qty' | t }}
                  </label>
                  <input id="updates_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-input" type="number"
                    value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*"
                    data-quantity-input data-quantity-item="{{ forloop.index }}" data-quantity-input-mobile>
                </div>
                <div class="cart__qty-error-message-wrapper cart__qty-error-message-wrapper--mobile hide" role="alert" data-cart-quantity-error-message-wrapper>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.accessibility.error' | t }} </span>
                  {% include 'icon-error' %}
                  <span class="cart__qty-error-message" data-cart-quantity-error-message></span>
                </div>
              </div>   
                    
                    <div class="qty_remove">
                        <div class="cart__quantity-td text-right small--hide">
                    <div class="cart_drawer__qty">
                      <label for="updates_large_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-label" data-quantity-label-desktop>{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}</label>
                       <span class="minus_cart_item">-</span>
                      <input id="updates_large_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-input" type="number"
                        name="updates[]" value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*"
                        data-quantity-input data-quantity-item="{{ forloop.index }}" data-quantity-input-desktop>
                       <span class="plus_cart_item">+</span>
                      
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart__qty-error-message-wrapper cart__qty-error-message-wrapper--desktop hide" role="alert" data-cart-quantity-error-message-wrapper>
                      <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.accessibility.error' | t }} </span>
                      {% include 'icon-error' %}
                      <span class="cart__qty-error-message" data-cart-quantity-error-message></span>
                    </div>
</div>                                    
                        <p class="cart__remove">
                      <a href="/cart/change?line={{ forloop.index }}&amp;quantity=0" class="text-link text-link--accent" aria-label="{{ 'cart.label.remove' | t: product: item.title }}" data-cart-remove>{{ 'cart.general.remove' | t }}</a>
                    </p>
                    </div>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div >   
            </div>
          {%- endfor -%}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reload Cart Page When Product Quantity is Changed

https://community.shopify.com/c/Technical-Q-A/Reload-Cart-Page-When-Product-Quantity-is-Changed/m-p/856240#M32729

```js
<script>
var firstChange = true;
function reloadCart(){
    var target = document.querySelector(`[data-cart-subtotal]`);

    if (!target)return
 
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (firstChange){
        firstChange = false;
        return;
    } else{
        firstChange = true;
         setTimeout(window.location.reload(), 1000);
    }
    
  });    
});
 
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
observer.observe(target, config);
    
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  
  reloadCart();
});
  
  selectElements = document.getElementsByClassName(`cart__qty-input`);
    var allOne = true;
  
  for (i = 0; i < selectElements.length; i++ ) {
        if (selectElements[i].getAttribute("value") > 1) {
            allOne = false;
        }
  }
//   console.log(allOne);
  if (allOne == true) {
    firstChange = false;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: This solution is not applicable because the OP (and mine) whole problem is that the cart subtotal and nothing in the cart updates to begin with.

Comment: then the OP marked this as answer by mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but an attempt being shared with community and fellow coder for help because I have worked a lot on this but unresolvable !

I am facing the same issue. Add 1st product to cart, cart appears but nothing inside cart. Add second product to cart--vola ! both products appears !! However, if I use shopify's regular 'Add to cart' button, even first product appears on first attempt of adding it and cart appears ok....

Code of added a new asset JS script called `atc-now.js` is as below. and it is added in theme.liquid appropriately with `defer` attribute.

Code preamble: I am capturing a .variant-button's click event for `add-to-cart` purpose in `atc-now.js` so that when .variant-button is clicked, item is added to cart drawer and drawer should appear with the product in it.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
 var variantBut = document.querySelector('.variant-button');  
    
 variantBut.addEventListener('click', function() 
 {
        var cart = document.querySelector(".drawer");
        let addToCartForms = document.querySelectorAll('form[action$="/cart/add"]');
      addToCartForms.forEach((form) => 
      {
        form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => 
        {
          e.preventDefault();
          let formData = new FormData(e.target);

          const config = {};
          if (cart) 
          {
            formData.append("sections", cart.getSectionsToRender().map((section) => section.id) );
            formData.append("sections_url", window.location.pathname);
            cart.setActiveElement(document.activeElement); 
          }

          config.body = formData;

          fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + "cart/add.js", {method: "POST", body: formData,})
            .then((response) => {return response.json();})
            .then((response) => { console.log(response); cart.renderContents(response);})
            .catch((error) => {console.error("Error:", error); });
        });
      });
    });
    
    });
```