# How to reload shopify cart after adding product through ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

I am using Shopify's default theme dawn and adding a product to cart using an ajax call. The issue is the cart doesnt auto update untill I reload the page.

I am adding product to cart using something like this

```
let formData = {
       'items': [{
        'id': productID,
        'quantity': 1
        }]
      };
      fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart/add.js', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
      })
      .then(response => {
        drawer.renderContents(response);
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
     
    }
  });
```

Got this snipper from shopify api documentation. The product itself is being added and works fine. The issue is the cart drawer isnt refreshed untill I refresh the page. How do I refresh the cart drawer after adding the product without having the refresh the page. I am using default Dawn Cart Drawer.

Comment: same problem here. Cart drawer not refreshing. You may also like to refer [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68692507/update-cart-drawer-without-reloading-the-page-in-shopify/77209239#77209239