# Auto refresh items in side cart of shopify prestige theme

Tags: php, ajax, shopify, liquid, cart

I'm currently working on a Shopify store using the newest Prestige theme, and I've customized the cart functionality using the custom.js file. For now, I am encountering an issue where the cart does not automatically refresh with every added item. I have to perform a hard refresh to see the updated cart contents.

Below is the relevant section of my custom.js code responsible for the cart drawer functionality:

```
// Function to update the cart items inside the cart drawer
function updateCartItems(cart) {
    const cartDrawer = document.querySelector('.cart-drawer');
    if (!cartDrawer) return;

    const cartItems = cart.items || [];
    const cartItemsContainer = cartDrawer.querySelector('.cart-items-container');

    // Clear the current cart items display
    cartItemsContainer.innerHTML = '';

    // Loop through cart items and add them to the cart drawer
    cartItems.forEach(function (item) {
        const itemDiv = document.createElement('div');
        itemDiv.textContent = item.title + ' x ' + item.quantity;
        cartItemsContainer.appendChild(itemDiv);
    });
}

function onQuickBuyButtonClicked(id, pro_id) {
    const CartCount = document.getElementsByClassName('Header__CartCount')[0];

    $(".loader_" + id).addClass("add-success--adding");
    const product = {
        id: id,
        quantity: 1
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/cart/add.js',
        data: JSON.stringify(product),
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        success: function (cart) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding");
                $(".loader_" + id).addClass("add-success--added");
                // cartRecommended(pro_id);



                // Trigger the 'cart:refresh' event to update the cart count in the header
                document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('cart:refresh', {
                    bubbles: true,
                    detail: {
                        variant: cart
                    }
                }));
            }, 500);

                          // Update the cart items inside the cart drawer immediately
                updateCartItems(cart);

            setTimeout(function () {
                $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding").removeClass("add-success--added");
            }, 1600);
            setTimeout(function () {
                // $('#backdrop').addClass('backdrop_active');
            }, 2000);
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding");

            var r = jQuery.parseJSON(errorThrown.responseText);
            $(".error_" + pro_id).html("Error: " + r.description).show();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(".error_" + pro_id).html("").hide(100);
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
    return false;
}

// Function to update the cart items when multiple items are added
function updateCartOnItemAdded() {
    ShopifyAPI.getCart(function (cart) {
        updateCartItems(cart);
    });
}

// Listen for the 'cart:refresh' event and update the cart items inside the cart drawer
document.addEventListener('cart:refresh', function () {
    $.getJSON('/cart.js', function (cart) {
        const cartCount = cart.item_count || 0;
        const CartCount = document.getElementsByClassName('Header__CartCount')[0];
        if (CartCount) {
            CartCount.innerHTML = cartCount;
        }

        // Update the cart items inside the cart drawer
        updateCartItems(cart);
    });
});

// Listen for the 'cart:item_added' event and update the cart items inside the cart drawer
document.addEventListener('cart:item_added', function () {
    // Since the 'cart:refresh' event is not always triggered by all themes,
    // call the updateCartOnItemAdded function directly here to update the cart items
    updateCartOnItemAdded();
});
```

I hope any of you can point me in the correct direction, or share any possible solutions you have used in your own projects.

Comment: Any working example which states the issue, and steps to recreate on the frontend?

Comment: this is a link to my website: www.winnerforce-lb.com

Comment: It works fine when adding from the quick add button from the homepage, and the sidebar cart auto updates the product listing without any issues.

Comment: same problem here. you may like to go through [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68692507/update-cart-drawer-without-reloading-the-page-in-shopify/77209239#77209239